# No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:64256/Registration.html

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1

I have a asp.net core 2.1 app, where I wrote couple of API's. Now in same solution I added a `html` page to test the API's,

[image]

I also changes launch browser settings to the `html` page. Now while I'm trying to browse the page, I'm getting error over browser,

> No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:64256/Registration.html

Can I do this, am I missing any settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static files should be added to wwwroot

In .net core you have to enable static files. You can do so by adding UseStaticFiles() to the application builder in your Configure method of your Startup class.

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```